# CSS Sprite Hover Positioning

Tags: css, css-sprites, rollover

I am trying to build a simply navigation that has rollover states and different icons for each item. I am using 3 different sprites for the on/off states for the icons and I have everything working great except I am having trouble positioning the icons themselves to sit flust left and aligned with the text. right now they appear in the top left corner of each list item, i want them to appear just to the left of the text. but when i add margin or padding or positioning it screws with the sprite and when rolled over you see the entire image vs just the portion i want. here is my code:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub">Subscribe &cent;99/month</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="profile">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="log last">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
#navcontainer  {
    width: 243px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#navcontainer ul  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type:  none;
    font-family: 'FranklinGothic-Book', sans-serif;
}

#navcontainer a  {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 0px 14px 45px;
    width: 198px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

#navcontainer a: link, #navlist a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navcontainer a: hover {
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
    color: #000;
}

#navcontainer a.last  {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

a.sub  {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url("http://vpointproductions.com/images/sub.png") no-repeat;
}

a.profile  {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url("http://vpointproductions.com/images/profile.png") no-repeat;
}

a.log  {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url("http://vpointproductions.com/images/log.png") no-repeat;
}

a.sub: hover, a.profile:hover, a.log:hover  {
    background-position: -20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do what you're trying to do with `a sprite`. The only way would be to really space the items out on your `sprite` so that you don't see the other elements of the sprite.

Alternatively you could just use two images per `a` tag and swap them on `hover`.

Another way you could do it would be to place `a span` inside the `a` tag and set the background on that rather than on the `a` tag.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with method 2 you suggested: using a bg image swap on a hover. applied specific styles to each item:a.sub  {background:url(images/sub-g.png) no-repeat 10px 14px;}
a:hover.sub  {background:url(images/sub-w.png) no-repeat 10px 14px;}
a.profile  {background:url(images/profile-g.png) no-repeat 10px 14px}
a:hover.profile {background:url(images/profile-w.png) no-repeat 10px 14px;}
a.log  {background:url(images/log-g.png) no-repeat 10px 14px;}
a:hover.log {background:url(images/log-w.png) no-repeat 10px 14px;}